# Problem about irreducible veriety in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here is an exercise I have to solve:

Consider the variety $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}_{w,x,y,z}^{4}$ with four defining equations given via the following matrix equations:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
w & x \\
y & z
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
w & x \\
y & z
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
w & x\\
y & z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Decompose $X$ as a union of finitely many irreducible varieties.

So far I have been able to come up with the system:

$$
\begin{cases}
w^2 - w + xy = 0 \\
x(w+z-1) = 0 \\
y(w+z-1) = 0 \\
z^2 - z + xy = 0 
\end{cases}
$$

But I don't see where to go from there... 
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like $x=y$ and then $w=z$.

Comment: If x=0, everything else must be 0, too. If x is not 0, w+z=1 (and y is not 0, too). I guess using w²-w=z²-z (by the first and the last equation) helps now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this type of problem can be solved by a computer algebra system by computing the primary decomposition of the defining ideal. In your case you obtain that $X$ is the union of the varieties $X_1=\{z+w-1=xy+w^2-w=0\}$, $X_2=\{w-1=z-1=x=y=0\}$ and $X_3=\{x=y=z=w=0\}$. Not that $X_2$ and $X_3$ are points and $X_1$ is a surface.

Now, let us work this out by hand. From the second and third equation you get that either $x=y=0$ (call this case 1) or $w+z-1=0$ (call this case 2).

In case 1, the equations one and four become $w^2-w=w(w-1)=0$ and $z^2-z=z(z-1)=0$, respectively. This gives the possibilities $$z=w=0,\ z=w-1=0,\ w=z-1=0,\ z-1=w-1=0.$$ We'll come back to this later.

In case 2, $w+z-1=0$ means that we can substitute one of $z$ or $w$ in equation one or four. First, $w=1-z$ plugged into the first equation gives us $0=xy+z^2-z$. The same way, plugging $z=1-w$ into the fourth equation gives $0=xy+w^2-w$. To sum up, $$w+z-1=0,\ xy+w^2-w=xy+z^2-z=0.$$

Let us gather together all of the different cases. We were obtaining the following equations $$x=y=z=w=0,\\ x=y=z=w-1=0, \\ x=y=w=z-1=0,\\ x=y=z-1=w-1=0,\\ w+z-1=xy+w^2-w=xy+z^2-z=0. $$

We are close to being done, what is left is to perform the same procedure to the last equation. This then gives you even more equations and you then have to check whether there are some inclusions between the varieties defined by this equations. Can you proceed from here on?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did the calculation by hand and found 2 varieties so I must have done something wrong... The thing is I don't really know how to check that a variety is irreducible (lecture wasn't great) apart from checking if the variety ideal is prime (which can be kind of tedious sometime!

Comment: I added some computations that you'll hopefully find helpful. Let me know if there are any questions (or errors in my computation).

Comment: Thanks again! This is very helpful, I did find some of the solutions but not all of them. I'll now try to finish it on my own! Cheers

Comment: Did it work out? If so, you may consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: Yes thank you it allowed me to finish the exercise! I am new here, I didn't really know how it worked ;)